# Intl.RelativeTimeFormat but with both minutes and seconds, hours and minutes, days and hours

Tags: javascript

I would like to know how I can make a function that would take a timestamp and returns a relative time format that would display for example `in 2 hours and 15 minutes`, `in 2 minutes and 15 seconds`, `one day and 6 hours ago`, `6 hours and 13 minutes ago`.

It has to use `Intl.RelativeTimeFormat` so that it is localized automatically.

I already have this function but it only display one unit instead of two at the same time.

```
const fromNow = function (timestamp) {
  const now = Date.now();
  const diff = timestamp - now;
  const days = diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
  const hours = (diff % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60);
  const minutes = (diff % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60);
  const seconds = (diff % (1000 * 60)) / 1000;
  const relative = new Intl.RelativeTimeFormat();

  if (diff > 0) {
    // If the difference is positive, the timestamp is in the future
    if (days >= 1) {
      return `${relative.format(Math.round(days), "day")}`;
    }
    if (hours >= 1) {
      return relative.format(Math.round(hours), "hour");
    }
    if (minutes >= 1) {
      return relative.format(Math.round(minutes), "minute");
    }
    if (seconds >= 0) {
      return relative.format(Math.round(seconds), "second");
    }
  }
  if (diff < 0) {
    // If the difference is negative, the timestamp is in the past
    if (Math.abs(days) >= 1) {
      return relative.format(Math.round(days), "day");
    }
    if (Math.abs(hours) >= 1) {
      return relative.format(Math.round(hours), "hour");
    }
    if (Math.abs(minutes) >= 1) {
      return relative.format(Math.round(minutes), "minute");
    }
    if (Math.abs(seconds) >= 0) {
      return relative.format(Math.round(seconds), "second");
    }
  }
  return "";
};
export default fromNow;
```

Comment: were you able to solve this?

Comment: @raquelhortab no